# scrollview doesn't work in my layout

Tags: android, layout

I use this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:background="#00868B">


<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        />
  <EditText

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


  />

   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  />


 <Button ..
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:text="@string/getloc" 

    />

 <Button ..
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 


     />

 <Button ..
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  ..
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

    />

</RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

There is no scrollview.
I want when the user enters sth in second textview to "go down" because else the textview gets bigger but the first button is steady and blocks the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid buttons going up when the keyboard appears you could put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on the activity node of your Android Manifest. Then, they won't bother you when typing.

Comment: :Mainly ,I want to use the scrollview.I tried what you say but still the same.

Comment: yes, same prob I am facing -------- scrollview doesn't work with adjustNothing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:background="#00868B">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"   
     >

<RelativeLayout 

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"


  <EditText

  />

   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    <EditText

  />
    </RelativeLayout>
<Button 

    />

 <Button 

     />

 <Button

    />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```